# Find a constraint column name using INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS in SQL

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a primary key constraint set up in a table - "tCustomerSessions" with the name "PK_tCustomerSessions".

Below is my query -

```
SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'tCustomerSessions'
    AND Constraint_Type = 'PRIMARY KEY'
```

Here how do i get the name of the column on which the primary key constraint has been set up ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the unique constraint columns list (in TSQL)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2675168/get-the-unique-constraint-columns-list-in-tsql)

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT
    tc.CONSTRAINT_NAME
  , ccu.COLUMN_NAME
FROM
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS AS tc
    JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE AS ccu ON ccu.CONSTRAINT_NAME = tc.CONSTRAINT_NAME
WHERE
    tc.TABLE_NAME = 'tCustomerSessions'
    AND tc.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
```